# No properties to serialize found on class com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue$ServerTimestampFieldValue

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm using [React Native Firebase Firestore](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/firestore/transactions) to store Server Timestamp. I have following code to add to store data in Firestore.

```
const data = {
        userid: this.props.user.id,
        created_at: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    }

firebase.firestore().collection('users').add(data).then(function (docRef) {
        alert('Successfully sent friend request!');
    }).catch(function (error) {
        alert(error);
    });
```

But I have an error after executing this code. [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul6cY.png)